# Error при подключении MySQL к node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, база-данных

```
var mysql = require('mysql2');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "myusername",
  password: "mypassword"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Connected!");
});
```

Установил MySQL 2 и при подключении к node.js выдает такую ошибку:

> `Yallist.prototype.splice = function (start, deleteCount, ...nodes) {`

Comment: версия node js 5.9

Comment: А если указать имя базы данных, как это описано в API `createConnection({..., database:'name'})`?

Comment: тоже самое получается (

Comment: Какая версия mysql2? Скорее всего просто не поддерживается эта версия nodejs уже. Если хотите использовать именно v5.9 node js - придется старый пакет npm использовать. А если выбор версии не обусловлен миром во всем мире (зависимости не требуют 5.9) - лучше используйте более современную версию node js.